# Hyperboloid plot using Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

My function $4x^2+4y^2-z^2=1$
I want like this photo that I use geogebra [!Geogebra 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcilO.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcilO.jpg)

```
import graph3; currentprojection=orthographic(1,1,1);
size(10cm);
real sign(real x){if (x<0) {return -1;} else {return 1;}} triple f(pair t){return (sinh(t.y)*cos(t.x)/2,sinh(t.y)*sin(t.x)/2,sign(t.y)* cosh(t.y));} 
surface s=surface(f,(0,-2) ,(2*pi,2),Spline);
draw(s,cyan+opacity(0.9),blue+0.6bp,render(merge=true));
xaxis3(Label("$x$"),Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$"),Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$"),Arrow3);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a sign error in my comments, so got `cosh` and `sinh` mixed up, sorry!

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(5,4,4);
size3(100);
triple f(pair t){return (cosh(t.y)*cos(t.x)/2,cosh(t.y)*sin(t.x)/2, sinh(t.y));}
surface s=surface(f,(0,-2) ,(2*pi,2),nu=40,nv=40,Spline);
draw(s,green+opacity(0.9),render(merge=true));
xaxis3(Label("$x$"),p=blue ,Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$"),p=blue ,Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$"),p=blue ,Arrow3);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Really thank so much!